# what are the google APIs to manage policies to block/restrict add-in(s) in google/Gsuite

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-directory-api

I have a requirement to block/restrict specific add-ins for user(s) in accessing. I could able to block add-ins using google admin portal ( Security -> API Control), which solves the problem but instead of doing this manually, I would like to automate the same using google APIs. I tried to explore users, tokens, etc APIs but could not find an option. Appreciate if you can suggest an option to achieve this functionality through API. Providing more details for better understanding: To get the list of users, I am using Directory API :  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list?apix_params=%7B%22customer%22%3A%22my_customer%22%7D and to get list of apps installed by the user I am using Directory API : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens/list?apix_params=%7B%22userKey%22%3A%22test%40test.net%22%7D Now I would like to block a specific app for specific user using Directory API. Similar feature in Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/conditionalaccesspolicy?view=graph-rest-1.0

Adding feature request link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174422078

Comment: I have a requirement to block/restrict specific add-ins for user(s) in accessing. I could able to block add-ins using google admin portal ( Security -> API Control), which solves the problem but instead of doing this manually, I would like to automate the same using google APIs. I tried to explore users, tokens, etc APIs but could not find an option. Appreciate if you can suggest an option to achieve this functionality through API.

Comment: You can still edit the question.

Comment: @Cooper I changed the main description to what I am looking for

Comment: @Cooper can you please change it to open?

Comment: Try creating a feature request in the **issuetracker**. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster updated question

Comment: Appreciate if you have any suggestions to address this issue.

Comment: [Delete the token](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens/delete)? You can also use gcloud cli to [disable the respective apis](https://support.google.com/gsuitemigrate/answer/9222865)

Comment: Delete token will work but the user can install & use the addon again. I would like to block specific add-on permanently

Comment: Consider creating a feature request in the issuetracker and linking it in your question. If  there's a api, Google guys will refer you to it.

Comment: adding feature request for reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174422078

Comment: [Edit] your question or consider adding the feature request link as a answer. Comments will be deleted.